# Can a stored procedure return more than 1 value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there anyway a stored procedure can return a list of values e.g. a column named as `ClientName` and returns all client names.

I don't want to create a view or another table, it has to be done in a stored procedure or if there is any other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stored procedure can return rowset

```
create procedure sp_Test
as
begin
    select 'Name1' as ClientName union all
    select 'Name2' as ClientName
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetClientsNames
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT Name AS 'ClientName'
   FROM Clients
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can create [SQL Server stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) with returning dataset. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName
AS
SELECT ClientName From yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_AllClients

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT ClientName From YourTable
END
```

To get the List of ClientNames execute Procedure

```
exec Sp_AllClients
```